# Knowing the end of a TCP stream with python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, server, client

**edit: I flagged question as too broad because I didn't know what I was asking. I have a better understanding now and will play with it some more before asking again.**

I'm writing a **very** simple TCP forwarding script in python. At least I think that's what I should call it.

Essentially I'm given a challenge to reverse engineer a proprietary protocol over TCP. I'm attempting to collect a full 'cycle' of data between two endpoints with wireshark. Originally, I was trying to do this with netcat, but I think the first connection (green below) needs the response on the same socket, which I am giving from a different netcat invocation.

[image]

Rather than do the 6-byte transfer manually (eg. `echo -e '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' | nc host port`), I figure I can open up a server socket with python, receive the green data, open a client socket that'll send the green data, receive the blue data with the client socket, and then finally reply with server socket with the blue data, to complete the cycle.

AFAIK there is no way to determine when I've `recv`'d all the bytes of a transfer, and I feel that implementing my own "end transfer" protocol on top of another protocol is bad news.

tl;dr **Is it possible to know when a TCP data stream is finished with python sockets?**

Comment: you need to define "finished" ... if recv returns an empty string it means there was no data left to recv ... that might be what you want. more than likely there is a byte sequence that your endpoint uses to signal that the message is done(maybe... maybe not ... look for repeating sequences in a raw stream)....

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html

Comment: If you're forwarding, you don't need to know when you've received a whole message. Just forward anything you get. When you receive EOF in one direction, use `shutdown()` to close the write direction of the forwarding socket.